# PHP echo header links from 2 different sessions

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-3

I just created an admin login application so I also had to change the links that are in my header when an admin is logged in.

So I used to have these links in my header:

```php
<li>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged'] == true){
            echo '<a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/user/profile">Profile</a>';
        }
    ?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged'] == true){
            echo '<a class="l4" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/logout">Uitloggen</a>';
        } else {
            echo'<a class="l5" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/register">Registrate</a>';
            echo '</li><li>';
            echo '<a class="l6" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/login">Login</a>';
        }
    ?>
</li>
<li>
    <a class"l7" href="<?= base_url() ?>/Product">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btnca">Cadeau aanbieden</button>
    </a>
</li>
```

So when a user is logged in is shows a link button with profile.
Now what I want is when a Admin is logged in, there must be a button called Admin dashboard INSTEAD of the profile button.

That is the only change that I want.. all the other links should stay on the same place for example registrate and login when a user is logged out.

I tried to do it like this but it doesn't work when I try it like this:

```php
<li>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged'] == true) {
            echo '<a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/user/profile">Account</a>';
        }
    ?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['admin_logged']) && $_SESSION['admin_logged'] == true){
            echo '<a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/IndexController">Admin dashboard</a>';
    }?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php
        if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged'] == true) {
            echo '<a class="l4" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/logout">Uitloggen</a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a class="l5" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/register">Registreren</a>';
            echo '</li><li>';
            echo '<a class="l6" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/login">Inloggen</a>';
        }
    ?>
</li>
<li>
    <a class"l7" href="<?= base_url() ?>/Product">
        <button type="button"   class="btn btn-default btnca">Cadeau aanbieden</button>
    </a>
</li>
```

Does anyone have a solution? 
When I'm logged in as an admin I don't see the logout button but I see the registrate and login button...

Comment: you can try  `!empty()` instead of `isset()`

Comment: where? in the line of the admin dashboard? : <li><?php if(empty($_SESSION['admin_logged']) && $_SESSION['admin_logged'] == true){
                    echo '<a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/IndexController">Admin dashboard</a>';
                    }?></li>  like that?

Comment: it doesnt work because i dont see the dashboard button than

Comment: @Learningprogrammingphp44 Does `$_SESSION['admin_logged']` have value in all files using sessions? What you posted should theoretically work. Did you check for possible errors with php's error reporting? what does a `var_dump($_SESSION['admin_logged']);` produce and viewing the HTML source?

Comment: $_SESSION['admin_logged']);  does have value and its just to see if an admin is logged in. But what happens when I add the admin dashboard button is that I don't see the logout button on the other side of the header but I see the registrate and login button when logged in as an admin..

Comment: @Learningprogrammingphp44 it's simple then, you seem to only be accepting one user logged in at a time. You would need to use a different operator to check for "both" "if/or" session arrays.

Comment: yeh true but what operator do i use, i cannot use <?php or   right?

Comment: Edited my answer with admin solution. Give it a try ;) it will work.

Comment: Thanks I'll try ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

During login (at login script) set the following `$_SESSION`:

```
/**
* Define user_level:
* 1 = 'normal user'
* 10 = 'admin user'
*/
// For user:
$_SESSION['user_level'] = 1;

// For admin:
$_SESSION['user_level'] = 10;
```

**Now the code:**

```
<li>
    <?php
    if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1): ?>
        <a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/user/profile">Account</a>
    <?php endif;?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 10):?>
        <a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/IndexController">Admin dashboard</a>
    <?php endif; ?>
</li>
<li>
    <?php if($_SESSION['user_level'] <= 10):?>
        <a class="l4" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/logout">Uitloggen</a>
    <?php else: ?>
        <a class="l5" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/register">Registreren</a>
        </li><li>
        <a class="l6" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/login">Inloggen</a>
    <?php endif ;?>
</li>
```

Comment: Yeh true but thats not the problem right now that I have

Comment: I see, second. I change it.

Comment: What I have is that I created a new table called 'admin'. is that correct?

Comment: Yes. You have a database, which might be called users. In users your have different columns. For example: `id`, `name` and `admin`. Admin should be 0 for every user, just for admins it should be 1.

Comment: I dont think you really understand my question, What I want is that if the admin is logged in, I want it to echo this button: <li><?php if(isset($_SESSION['admin_logged']) && $_SESSION['admin_logged'] == true){
                    echo '<a class="l3" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/IndexController">Admin dashboard</a>';
                    }?></li>  and if the user is logged in I want it to echo the other button called 'profile'

Comment: I do understand your question. Try to follow what I mean: You need to check if a user is an admin to display something which is related to this user. If $_SESSION['admin_logged'] is correctly set it should display your echo'ed text. Something is going wrong here. Can you <pre>var_dump($_SESSION)</pre> for me? and check which are set? Let's start there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158700/discussion-between-ronnie-oosting-and-learningprogrammingphp44).

Comment: Yes it does display the echo'ed text but the thing is I don't see the logout button which is supposed to echo instead of the login and registration buttons when an admin is logged in. This is the logout button that is supposed to echo instead of login and registration buttons when an admin is logged in: <?php if(isset($_SESSION['user_logged']) && $_SESSION['user_logged'] == true) {
        echo '<a class="l4" href="https://kadokado-ferran10.c9users.io/auth/logout">Uitloggen</a>';
    }